# Footnote mark in regular size

Tags: footnotes, size

Is it possible to set the footnote mark into a regular size (rather than exponent) and between brackets?
Actually, I would like to put some bibliography in the footer, something like :

Blablabla [1]
Blablabla

---

[1] Author - Article

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redefined `\@makefnmark` as per the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{[\normalfont\@thefnmark]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is test.\footnote{Test footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To get also the footnote in normal size you may want to redefine `\footnotesize` to `\normalsize` with e.g. `\let\footnotesize\normalsize`. A disadvantage then is that `\footnotesize` disappears. To define a user footnote size command in `\oldfootnotesize` one can use `\futurelet\oldfootnotesize\let\footnotesize\normalsize`.

Comment: @StefanH I too made the mistake of misinterpreting the question in this way. I don't know how I could have, it seems quite clear now in retrospect. OT aks about the footnote mark, not the footnote-text.

Comment: Let us view it as an extra feature:)